# Indirect reference following brackets in scientific literature

Tags: academic-writing, grammar

I've got a bracketed reference in a scientific manuscript I'm writing, that immediately follows bracketed text like so:

...rather than visiting flowers that were in ‘same scent’ group (same scent and different colour to the rewarding flower group) (Figure 1).

Is this considered grammatically incorrect?

It doesn't look right to me, but I'm not sure how I could correct it, if I need to. I could directly reference the figure earlier on in the sentence, but it would be more convenient for my writing if I could fix the issue at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Can you please tell me more information? I’m not sure what the question is. Maybe cite a piece of text from your writing as an example?

Comment: @Leila The question as I understand it is whether it's okay to put a reference (in brackets) immediately after another piece of text which is also in brackets

Comment: That wording makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, @DM_with_secrets got it right. I'm asking if it's grammatically incorrect to have two bracketed pieces of text next to each other, if one is a reference. I've edited the post with the actual text in question.

Comment: Review the submission guidelines of the journal to which you will be submitting.  They will usually have explicit rules for you to follow when formatting references to figures.  (And browse through the journal to find examples.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this usage is grammatically *incorrect*, though it may not be best practices. But it's easily fixed.  You can merge the parentheticals, like so:

> ..rather than visiting flowers that were in ‘same scent’ group (same
> scent and different colour to the rewarding flower group. See Figure
> 1).

or remove the first:

> ..rather than visiting flowers that were in ‘same scent’ group: same
> scent and different colour to the rewarding flower group. (Figure 1)

which you would do depends on whether the figure in question is more closely relates to the parenthetical or to the statement as a whole.